# LINQ Filtering a List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a List<Product> in memory. It contains all products from my database. This is kept in the Cache.

Depending on the QueryString I need to filter that list of products and bind a repeater to it.

So I am applying a LINQ .Where clause to my list, but as you know the Where returns IEnumerable<Product>

so if I have

```
var category = "Beverages";
var filteredProducts = allProducts.Where(p => p.Category = category);
```

what will happen when I call filteredProducts.ToList()?

Note that allProducts is a List<Product>() and contains approx 300 items.

I guess it will create a new List<Product> in memory and will copy the relevant items from allProducts list.

The filteredProducts is approx. 60 items.

How bad in terms of performance is that?

**Edit**: It is a web app, so we are talking about let's say tens of requests at once to this page and this may affect the performance.

Comment: probably better than you writing your own loop for putting them in a list. As an aside, there's not 1 clear answer to your question, its kind of open ended

Comment: 60 items....piece of cake

Comment: that's fine.  60 or 300 will be nothing you'll notice in terms of performance.  When you get on the scale of millions you may want to look back on it

Comment: Check if the Repeater binds to an IEnumerable? In that case, you don't have to convert it to a list.

Comment: It will only copy the references anyway (I assume you have a class not a struct). Nothing risky from memory perspective.

Comment: And as for performance.. there are multiple aspects.. If one were to talk in theory, then obviously the alternatives you have will impact both CPU and Memory (in terms of garbage created). If it is meaning full enough, is very subjective to your scenario. You may find this overhead to be very much acceptable (on an average, very likely), or your app is super sensitive to smallest amounts of latency and memory pressure added (less likely - but only you can tell).

Comment: Your remark "I guess it will create a new List<Product> in memory and will copy the relevant items from allProducts list." is wrong. It will not copy the relevant items. It will give you a new list with 60 references back to the same objects from the original list. If you change something in those objects, they will be changes in both collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felt like writing some silly code for demonstration purposes. The purpose of this demo is for you to see that only *references* to the objects are copied to the newly created list when calling `.ToList()` on your `IEnumerable`. So, the underlying objects are the same both in your original list as well as in your new list.  This has two implications. First, there was no inefficient deep copy of your objects.  Second, changes made to items in the original list and to items in the new list will affect both lists, as the objects are **the same** in memory. Plop this into a console app to see the output.

```
class Program
{
    class Dog
    {            
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool isAGoodBoy { get; set;}
        public Dog(string name, bool isAGoodBoy)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.isAGoodBoy = isAGoodBoy;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        List<Dog> doges = new List<Dog>();
        doges.Add(new Dog("Rufus", true));
        doges.Add(new Dog("Kevin", false)); //chewed furniture
        doges.Add(new Dog("Maximus", true));

        IEnumerable<Dog> goodBoys = doges.Where(doggy => doggy.isAGoodBoy);
        List<Dog> goodBoysList = goodBoys.ToList();
        foreach (var goodBoy in goodBoysList)   //Iterate over NEW list
        {
            goodBoy.isAGoodBoy = false;    //They wouldn't stop barking
        }

        //From original list! You'll see all of these will output 'False'
        Console.WriteLine("Is Rufus good? " + doges[0].isAGoodBoy.ToString());    
        Console.WriteLine("Is Kevin good? " + doges[1].isAGoodBoy.ToString());    
        Console.WriteLine("Is Maximus good? " + doges[2].isAGoodBoy.ToString());    

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```